# Разбор примера с асинхронными запросами

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio, aiohttp

В [базовом](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html) примере `aiohttp` всё очень сложно. Для чего такие сложности с контекстами?

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.text())
```

Зачем тут используется второй, вложенный контекст. Какую роль он играет? Более того, он почему-то делает `await` (ну или просто подвисает), хотя в коде этого явно не указано. Также почему-то происходит `await resp.text()`. Зачем он нужен, если он есть на уровне **get-request**?

---

Один из возможных способов использования следующий

```
resp = await session.get()
await resp.text()
await resp.close()
```

Вопрос. Что происходит в каждой строке? Почему используется 3 `await`, вместо 1?

---

Часть ответа есть здесь. Но пока что не ясно, для чего использовать `await` с `close`?

Comment: Ну это надо детали реализации смотреть, что там происходит при вызовах await. Например, может быть открыта сессия (надо разрезолвить dns, соединиться с сервером, поговорить с ним - а есть ли у него такая страница), а потом отдельно получено уже содержимое с сервера. И я не считаю использование with чем-то сложным, наоборот это хороший и удобный стиль - мы инициализировали объект и он потом при выходе из блока сам закроет всё, что ему нужно, без вызова нами всяких там close вручную. Красота же.

Comment: await с close - ну может с сервером установлено некое соединение (сессия) через которую мы можем не только ответ-страницу получить, но и ещё что-то сделать. close эту сессию закрывает, как-то общаясь с сервером, а там мало ли - может сервер задумчивый, поэтому лучше асинхронно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну, я понимаю. Я ж не просто так вопрос задал. Вероятно, кто-то смотрел детали реализации. Учитывая то, что aiohttp сделан не очень понятно. Это барьер для меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.text())
```

Переписывается это на 5 await (хотя на мой взглад тут нужно 6), так:

```
session = await aiohttp.ClientSession()
```

первый await - возможна работа с файлами, с куками, например. await нужен чтоб не блокировать паралельные таски если есть. Готовит несколько сокетов на коннекты.

```
resp = await session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
```

Установка соединения и отправка запроса - тут понятно. Получение ответа началось.

```
print(resp.status)
```

на `get` клиент читает первые строки ответа, до `\r\n\r\n` - вместе с хидерами.

```
print(await resp.text())
```

Перед тем как читать остальной текст можно решить нужен ли он нам. там может быть и видео на 100ГБ и ничего.

```
await resp.close()
```

Дальше нужно закрыть соединение и вернуть сокет в сессию, чтоб им пожно было воспользоваться ещё раз.

```
await session.close()
```

Записать куки, закрыть сокеты.

Comment: Если сессию не закрываю?

Comment: ну не закрывайте, её нужно использовать на всё время работы программы обычно.